# Animation e Transform Rotate com ponto de referência

Tags: javascript, css, html5, drag-n-drop

Estou com uma dúvida se é possível realizar a seguinte funcionalidade:
Fiz uma codificação para drag and drop somente em uma área específica (A área rosa)
A área vermelha está como `droppable = false`
Tem como eu fazer uma rotação de imagem onde a mesma aponta para o ponto de referência (`ponto-referencia`)? Como na imagem a seguir : 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código como exemplo (rodando sem ponto de referência)

```js
   //Drag'n Drop functions
   var elementCounter = 0; // Para designar a ID do elemento dropado.

   function allowDrop(ev) {
    if (ev.target.getAttribute("droppable") == "false"){
     ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none"; // dropping is not allowed
     ev.preventDefault();
    } else {
     ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "all"; // drop it like it's hot
     ev.preventDefault();
    }
   }

   function drag(ev) {
    if(document.getElementById('conteudo').style.background!='rgb(255, 255, 255)') {
     ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
     ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy"; 
    } else {
     bootbox.alert("Selecione uma Pulseira.");
    }
   }

   function drop(ev,div) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   var x = ev.clientX;
   var y = ev.clientY;
   var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
   var copyimg = document.createElement("img");
   var original = document.getElementById(data);
   copyimg.src = original.src;
   div.appendChild(copyimg);
   if(original.parentNode.id == "conteudo"){ 
    if(ev.target.tagName == "IMG" ){ // Se a imagem estiver dropando em uma imagem
     original.parentNode.removeChild(original);
     copyimg.id = "dropped_elem" + (++elementCounter);
     copyimg.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: " + (y - 50) + "px; left:" + (x - 70) + "px;");
     copyimg.setAttribute('draggable', true);
     copyimg.setAttribute('ondragstart', "drag(event)");
    } else {                          // Se não, é porque a imagem está sendo dropada em uma div
     original.parentNode.removeChild(original);
     copyimg.id = "dropped_elem" + (++elementCounter);
     copyimg.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: " + (y - 50) + "px; left:" + (x - 50) + "px;");
     copyimg.setAttribute('draggable', true);
     copyimg.setAttribute('ondragstart', "drag(event)");
    }
   } else {
    if(ev.target.tagName == "DIV" ){  // Se a imagem está sendo movimentada dentro da div conteudo
     copyimg.id = "dropped_elem" + (++elementCounter);
     copyimg.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: " + (y - 50) + "px; left:" + (x - 50) + "px;");
     copyimg.setAttribute('draggable', true);
     copyimg.setAttribute('ondragstart', "drag(event)");
    } else {                          // Se não, é porque está sendo dropada na IMG
      copyimg.id = "dropped_elem" + (++elementCounter);
      copyimg.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: " + (y - 50) + "px; left:" + (x - 70) + "px;");
      copyimg.setAttribute('draggable', true);
      copyimg.setAttribute('ondragstart', "drag(event)");
     }
    }
   }
```

```css
#imagem{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  z-index:5;
     opacity:1; 
}

#conteudo > img{
animation: roll 4s infinite;
-webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}

@keyframes roll {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.conteudo-externo{
  width:500px;
  height:400px;
  z-index:3;
  background:red;
  border: 0px solid;
  float:left;
 }
 .conteudo{
  width:320px;
  height:300px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  z-index:5;
  background:#f1f;
     margin: 40px auto;
}
  .img{
   z-index:1;
   width:130px;
            height:130px
            background-position:center;
   opacity:0.5;
  }

 .conteudo-bloqueio{
  width:280px;
  height:260px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  z-index:5;
  background:red;
     margin: 20 auto;
     opacity:1;
    }

   #ponto-referencia{
    width:5px;
  height:5px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:3px solid #000;
  z-index:1;
  background:#000;
     margin: 120px auto;
   }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- Biblioetca JQuery -->
    </head>
 <body>
  <div id="imagem">
   <img id="drag1" src="http://www.esfcex.eb.mil.br/images/menu_cms/concurso_cms/divulgacoes/seta_para_baixo.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
  </div>
  <div class="conteudo-externo" id="conteudo-externo"> 
   <div id="conteudo" class="conteudo" ondrop="drop(event, this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <div id="conteudo-bloqueio" droppable="false" class="conteudo-bloqueio"> 
     <div id="ponto-referencia" droppable="false">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu usei o Rotate.js para resolver esta questão 
http://jqueryrotate.com